# Updating state of component from returned server data

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am injecting the props into the **initial state** of component. I want to change the if I click on some button inside the component I want to update the state and the data should be reflected **immediately**.

`eventData` is an object which contains two attributes one is key(another object) and other is array of object

Data Structure looks like :

> eventData--->
>
> ```
>     {
>     key:{}
>     events: [{},{},...]
>     }
> ```

```
    this.state = {      
    events:this.props.eventData.events,
    }


    static getDerivedStateFromProps(nextProps, prevState){
        if(nextProps.eventData.events!==prevState.events){
          return { events: nextProps.eventData.events};
       }
       else return null;
     }

     componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {

       const {eventData} = this.props;
       if(prevProps.eventData.events!==this.props.eventData.events){
         //Perform some operation here
         this.setState({events: eventData.events});
         this.classMethod();
       }
     }


 handleClickButton = (event, action) => {

      const {eventData} = this.props;


      axios.post(configs.Data.sendEvent, {events: event, key:eventData.key, action:action})//event here is a single event 
      .then(res=>{
           this.setState({events:res.data.singleResult.dataEvent});
      });

      };
```

Since I updated the state but the result is not reflected. Can I use **componentDidUpdate** to update state from upcoming updated state?

Comment: the change should have been reflected. Probably there is something wrong somewhere else. Maybe within render?

Comment: How are you rendering the output? Are you definitely getting a result back from the axios call? (e.g. can you console.log(res.data.singleResult.dataEvent and get what you expect)?

Comment: You should avoid using both componentDidUpdate and also getDerivedStateFromProps. There are some antipattern in your logic, IE: update same state attribute both directly and by props.

Comment: @Fermin yes I got the result as expected from axios but couldn't update the state

Comment: @MosèRaguzzini then how do I initialize my props to my state? since it's needed in my case

Comment: @FotisNalbadis I am rendering the output correct previous state data is coming okay-ish

Comment: @Kramer the first question you have to ask to yourself is: "while a props represent already a piece of a parent component state, why I do not use it directly from props and update it in parent state - AKA lift up the state - ? https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html

Comment: @MosèRaguzzini I am passing the props from parent to child only under certain condition let say on button click in parent component but I click my child component I need to update the state of my child using the props as initial state as parent's

Comment: @Kramer it is a wrong pattern, use always the upper state and provide an update method by props instead of decoupling values

Comment: @MosèRaguzzini tell me why I am not able to update the states directly using setState

Comment: That's not deterministic, because the state is updated by 3 different events (props, didUpdate and setState). setState() updates the state for sure, but it is difficult without a snippet reproducing the issue complexity to say if incoming data are wrong or overwritten by other logic in your class.

Comment: @MosèRaguzzini I figure it out it's because of synchronous nature of javascript...I logged the same value I got empty but when I am logging the result directly I am getting the output.........Which one should I use promise or async/await?

Comment: Javascript nature is not always sync, setState is async. In fact to be sure to log the right result you have to log it in its callback `setState({...obj}, () => console.log(this.state))`

Comment: @MosèRaguzzini I am getting redundant data why it is not overriding prev state?

Comment: `const res= await axios.post(configs.Data.sendEvent, {events: event, key:eventData.key, action:action})
      
        if(res.data.singleResult!=null)
          this.setState({events:[]});
        console.log(res.data.singleResult.dataEvent);
           res.data.singleResult.flightTask.forEach(element=>{
               events.push(element);
           });
           
            this.setState({...events}, ()=>console.log(this.state.events))
           
      };`

In console log I am getting redundant data not overriding previous data

Comment: Selected answer is correct and provide clear indications on how to lift the state

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to keep incoming data on parent component where props come from without touching componentDidUpdate(). Then pass a function from that component to make changes on state of that component. Then render child component again.

If you want to change both Parent component and Child components data,  you can try something like below. It's not a good method but it should work.

```
class Parent extends Component
{
  ....
  this.state = {dataFromSever:""}
  ...

  changeData = (data) => 
     {
     this.setState({dataFromServer:data});
     }
  ...

   render()
   {
       ...
        /* 
        * ReactDOM.unmountComponentAtNode is goint to unmount react component from 
        * 'container' component. 
        * For now, just consider 'container' where you put react components. 
        */
        ReactDOM.unmountComponentAtNode(document.getElementById('container'));
        ReactDOM.render(<ChildComponent changeData={this.changeData} 
        currentData={this.state.dataFromServer}> 
        </ChildComponent>,document.getElementById('container'));
        ...
   }

}
```

and

```
class ChildComponent extends Component
{
  ....
  ...

  handleClickButton = (event, action) => {

      const {eventData} = this.props;


      axios.post(configs.Data.sendEvent, {events: event, 
      flightTaskKey:eventData.flightKey, action:action})
      .then(res=>{
           this.props.changeData(res.data.singleResult.dataEvent);
      });

      };
  ...

   render()
   {
    ... <...> this.props.currentData </...>
   }

}
```